# Smoother Auto-Scrolling in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop switch statement which allows the user to grab a cell, the code seamlessly creates a snapshot of it, and then the user can drag the snapshot to a new position. Boom! Cell moved.

For when the amount of rows/cells is longer than the iPhone's screen, I added code to allow the user to drag up/down the table.

```
if locationOnScreen.y < 200 && indexPath!.row > 1 {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row-1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
} else if locationOnScreen.y > 550 && indexPath!.row < listCount {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row+1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
}
```

*Note: The cells vary in height, some take up half the screen height, others are much smaller.*

**Question**

This code works, but it snaps the table up/down quickly. It's great for quickly reaching the top or bottom of the table but not good for gradual scrolling. Any ideas?

Is there a way so that if the dragged cell is near the top, the table with scroll-up at a fixed rate per second? And if near the bottom, will scroll-down at a fixed rate per second?

Comment: you can try animateWithDuration to slow it down , with slow effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `animated: true`. It should scroll to cell with animation

```
if locationOnScreen.y < 200 && indexPath!.row > 1 {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row-1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
} else if locationOnScreen.y > 550 && indexPath!.row < listCount {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row+1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is still jerky. It might be because the cells vary in height, some take up half the screen height, others are much smaller. Is there a way so that if the dragged cell is near the top, the table with scroll-up at a fixed rate per second? And if near the bottom, will scroll-down at a fixed rate per second?

Comment: Did you figure this out Dave?